# What program for profiling is it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, profiling

I've seen screens like this a few times, send by guys from Unity etc. Does anyone know what program is this? It looks a little like Unity Dashboard, but I don't think it is there.

[image]

Comment: Not familier with that user interface, but can be the [unity profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html)?

Comment: My Unity profiler looks different, on all versions that I used it looks the same, but not like this.

Comment: Isn't it just Unity profiler? With changed view from timeline to hierarchy.

Comment: unity profiler is very complete and useful tool and its integrated in the engine itself. Not aware of any other comparable tool to profile.

Comment: Looks like XCode Instruments, UT people tend to showcase it in their presentations about profiling before delving in the internal in-editor profiler.